# Regain focus after a background task is completed

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

I have a datagridView(dgv) in the active tab(tabControl) that is filled with data obtained from a web service, when i start the query i create a separated thread that will assign the data to the dgv on his RunWorkerCompleted event, but then  the dgv doesn't select a row when i make a click on it, in order to work properly i have to select the other tab and select again the tab containing this dgv
[image: consulting web service]

[image: rows can't be selected until i change tab]

-the dgv still responds to the event cellContentClick
some code:

```
    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
            Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
            Try

                If UCA1.getAlumnos(codCarrrera, anio, ciclo, carnet_opc).alumnosArray IsNot Nothing Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To UCA1.getAlumnos(codCarrrera, anio, ciclo, carnet_opc).alumnosArray.Length - 1
                        Dim a As sv.edu.uca.wsprb.alumnos = UCA1.getAlumnos(codCarrrera, anio, ciclo, carnet_opc).alumnosArray(i)
                        'here i add the rows
                        'TablaFAlumno.Rows.Add(...)
                        If i < 10 Then
                            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10)
                        End If

                    Next
                Else
                    TablaFAlumno.Rows.Clear()
                End If
            Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
                MessageBox.Show("->" + ex.Message)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
  End Sub

    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 0 Then
            ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        End If
        If ProgressBar1.Value < 100 Then
            ProgressBar1.Value += 10
        End If            
    End Sub

 Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

        If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("E -->" + e.Error.Message)
        ElseIf e.Cancelled = True Then
            ProgressBar1.Visible = False
            MessageBox.Show("C -->" + e.Error.Message)
        End If

        ProgressBar1.Visible = False

        dgvAlumnos.DataSource = TablaFAlumno    

  End Sub
```

Comment: So **what's the actual question?** All I am seeing is datagridview doesn't select a row when you click on it. Have you thought about putting many available events into your class: DataGridViewCellMouseClick or another similar event to see if it's being hit when clicked; it would be a great start to see if it's being hit as you didn't mention how you tested this to confirm. It's also possible your just swallowing an exception which could block the main thread and hence why it's not getting focus? Could you provide some sort of code where you are handling this?

Answer (score 0):

try ad the end :

```
   ProgressBar1.Visible = False

      'TabControl name with Ficha Alumno
          Me.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0

         dgvAlumnos.DataSource = TablaFAlumno
         dvgAlumnos.Select()

   End Sub
```

Comment: this just select one row(blue background), but still not responding